# Format Message text with line feed notification.alert phonegap

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I would like to be able to display a message in a notification.alert in `phoneGap` that has multiple lines.  I don't think that `HTML` works there, and I've tried using `\n` to create a new line, but that just prints `\n`, no line feeds.  If that isn't possible with the dialog plugin, is it possible using another method.  The `\n` actually works with a conventional javascript alert, although the text is centered, not left justified.  Would be a nice feature, better yet if you could use HTML.
Is there another plug with a callback that works kind of the same way but allow formatting the text?

Comment: What works is "string1" + "\n" + "string2".

Comment: Now wondering if there is a way to left justify it.  As it is, each line is centered.  Might have something to do with my CSS in the DOM though.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
System.getProperty("line.separator")
```